# My Network Response shows in the console but won't save to my variable

Tags: reactjs, django-rest-framework, axios

I am using React.js and Axios to call a django api on my local machine. When I make the request and check the network console, the data is there. But when I try to save the response data to a variable and log the results, nothing shows. I have tried using jquery and gotten the same results.  It seems I can also only get the response data in the console when I use 'await'.

Portion of my Context-Provider.js code:

```
async componentDidMount() {
        var resp = await axios.get('http://localhost:8000/campaign/')
        .then((res) => {
        resp = res.data
        })
        console.log(resp)

        this.setState({
            campaigns: resp.data,

        })
    }
```

[Here is my consoles output for the network Response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CiuCA.png)

Answer (score 2):

Thinking about this more, it's probably a bad idea to combine `async/await` and `then`.  I would suggest you go with one or the other

```
axios.get('http://localhost:8000/campaign/')
.then((res) => {
  this.setState({ campaigns: res.data })
})
```

OR

```
const resp = await axios.get('http://localhost:8000/campaign/')
this.setState({ campaigns: resp.data })
```

Comment: I've changed it to this and it still doesn't seem to work. 
   ```async componentDidMount() {



        var resp = await axios.get('http://localhost:8000/campaign/')
        .then((res) => {
            return res.data
        })
        console.log(resp)

        this.setState({
            campaigns: resp,
           
        })
    } ```

Comment: After testing with console.log it seems that my axios call never finishes and goes down to the next line?